# Iterator invalidation - does end() count as an iterator or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, multimap

I ran into the following problem using `std::multimap::equal_range()` and `insert()`.

According to both [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/insert/) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert), `std::multimap::insert` does not invalidate any iterators, and yet the following code causes an infinite loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::multimap<std::string,int> testMap;
    testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("a", 1));
    testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("a", 2));
    testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("a", 3));

    auto range = testMap.equal_range(std::string("a"));
    for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
    {
        testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("b", it->second));
        // this loop becomes infinite
    }

    // never gets here
    for (auto it = testMap.begin(); it != testMap.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " - " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The intent is to take all existing items in the multimap with a particular key ("a" in this case) and duplicate them under a second key ("b"). In practice, what happens is that the first loop never exits, because `it` never ends up matching `range.second`. After the third element in the map is processed, `++it` leaves the iterator  pointing at the first of the newly inserted items.

I've tried this with VS2012, Clang, and GCC and the same thing seems to happen in all compilers, so I assume it's "correct". Am I reading too much into the statement "No iterators or references are invalidated."? Does `end()` not count as an iterator in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`multimap::equal_range` returns a `pair` whose second element in this case is an iterator to the past-the-end element ("which is the past-the-end value for the container" [container.requirements.general]/6).

I'll rewrite the code a bit to point something out:

```
auto iBeg = testMap.begin();
auto iEnd = testMap.end();

for(auto i = iBeg; i != iEnd; ++i)
{
    testMap.insert( std::make_pair("b", i->second) );
}
```

Here, `iEnd` contains a past-the-end iterator. The call to `multimap::insert` doesn't invalidate this iterator; it stays a valid past-the-end iterator. Therefore the loop is equivalent to:

```
for(auto i = iBeg; i != testMap.end(); ++i)
```

Which is of course an infinite loop if you keep adding elements.

Comment: Makes sense! I guess the question is what does "iterators are not invalidated" actually mean. The iterators themselves are still valid, but if iterating using them results in unexpected behaviour then it's not as simple as whether they're valid or not.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: "iterators aren't invalidated" means that the iterators are still valid, and still refer to the same element of the container (or in the case of an end iterator, still refer to the end of the container). It's kind of on you to deduce (and expect) the correct behaviour from that.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm still struggling to find an elegant solution to the problem. Maybe something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dcc237b71d6a764)?

Comment: @DyP: Nice! That's better than what I came up with, which was to stick the new elements in a temporary vector first.

Comment: Zeno is rolling over in his grave thanks to this one.

Answer (score 2):

The end-iterator `range.second` is not invalidated.

The reason that the loop is infinite, is that each repetition of the loop body:

- inserts a new element at the end of the map, thus increasing the distance between `it` and the end by one (so, after this insert, `range` no longer represents the `equal_range` for the key `"a"` because you have inserted a new key within the range it does represent, from the first `"a"` to the end of the container).
- increments `it`, reducing the distance between `it` and the end by one.

Hence, `it` never reaches the end.

Here's how I might write the loop you want:

```
for (auto it = testMap.lower_bound("a"); it != testMap.end() && it->first == "a"; ++it)
{
     testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("b", it->second));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to make it work as expected (feel free to improve, it's a community wiki)

```
auto range = testMap.equal_range(std::string("a"));
if(range.first != range.second)
{
    --range.second;
    for (auto it = range.first; it != std::next(range.second); ++it)
    {
        testMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("b", it->second));
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B. This is only safe if you *insert*. When you *remove*, you might invalidate `range.second`.

Comment: For that matter when you remove you might invalidate `it`, depending what you remove :-)